# How can I shorten the or operator?

Tags: javascript

```
if(x=='a'||x=='b'||x=='c'||x=='d'||x=='e'||x=='x'||x=='y'||x=='z'){
...
}
```

If I do like this, won't work anymore:

```
if(x=='a'||'b'||'c'||'d'||'e'||'x'||'y'||'z'){
...
}
```

So, what's the prefered way to do this?

Comment: array + `indexOf`, or even a regex `x.match(/^[abcdexyx]$/)`

Comment: You can even save two more letters :) `x.match(/^[a-exyz]$/)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot resist to put an answer after my comment gained <strike>10</strike> <strike>12</strike> 13 upvotes :-)

Use either:

1. `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'x', 'y', 'z'].indexOf(x) >= 0`
2. `x.match(/^[abcdexyz]$/)`
3. `'abcdexyz'.indexOf(x) > -1` credits to [@bigp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468206/bigp)

Just for fun: http://jsperf.com/single-char-lookup-zerkms

Comment: Provided that the search string and matching strings are only one character long, you could probably just do an indexOf(x) on a string instead of an array, too. (ex: `"abcdexyz".indexOf(x)>-1` )

Comment: @bigp: I am guessing that `abcdexyz` are just examples and no real values to compare with.

Comment: it's good, that the topic-starter had to make only 8 checks. Imagine, if he would have to check all 26 of them :)))

Comment: `indexOf()` should be the fastest of them all

Comment: Yeah probably, not really an universal solution for longer strings. I guess let's just go with it since the OP didn't specify if the example uses real values or not.

Comment: @zerkms, can you replace `indexOf( ... ) > -1` with `!=` and see what happens?

Comment: the chart labels are confusing "higher is better" which is just opposite >)

Comment: @injecteer: done. As expected nothing changed. "higher is better" --- it is correct. It's a number of operations per unit of time.

Comment: @zerkms well, in the results table, the `str` case was marked green as the fastest

Comment: @injecteer: `str` is fastest actually. PS: oh, only now noticed you asked about a change to `!=`. It should not change anything actually.